# trigger to populate contact's email based on the name field (look up field)

Tags: trigger, email, contact, before-trigger

Trying to figure something out. Working on this but its not working.

I have two fields in this one object under the account. One field is a contact name look up and the other is the email of the contact. The trigger is supposed to populate the email of the contact once the contact name is selected. Can you guys help me? thank you so much

```
trigger populateContactemail on Member_Assess__c (before insert , before update){

    Set<ID> setConIds = new Set<ID>();
    for(Member_Assess__c  obj : trigger.new){
        if(obj.Member_Name__c != null)
        setConIds.add(obj.Member_Name__c);
    }

     MAP<ID , Contact> mapCon = new MAP<ID , Contact>([Select Email__c from Contact where id in: setConIds]);
     for(Member_Assess__c  obj : trigger.new)
       {
        if(obj.Member_Name__c != null)
          {
            Contact  c = mapCon.get(obj.Member_Name__c);
            obj.email__c = c.email__c;
          }

       }
```

Comment: is `address__c` the email field?

Comment: oops. fixed hehe...

Comment: still not working though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Name for the email field on contact is `email` instead of `email__c`

```
trigger populateContactemail on Member_Assess__c (before insert , before update){
Set<ID> setConIds = new Set<ID>();
for(Member_Assess__c  obj : trigger.new){
    if(obj.Member_Name__c != null)
        setConIds.add(obj.Member_Name__c);
}
MAP<ID , Contact> mapCon = new MAP<ID , Contact>([Select Email__c from Contact where id in: setConIds]);
for(Member_Assess__c  obj : trigger.new)
{
    if(obj.Member_Name__c != null)
    {
        Contact  c = mapCon.get(obj.Member_Name__c);
        obj.email__c = c.email;
    }
}}
```

Let me know if this does not solve your problem.

Comment: Glad to help :)